# Custom Google App Script function not working: looking for Spreadsheet.getUI even though I'm not calling it

Tags: json, google-apps-script, custom-function

I'm trying to create a custom function in google App scripts where I converts some selected cells into a JSON text string.  The function works when I run the macro but I can't get it to work as a custom function in the spreadsheet such that it would return the text string in the cell.  I'm getting an error that says:

"Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 1)."

This is strange because nowhere in my code am i calling SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

```
/**
 * Returs JSON.
 * @return Json formated data
 * @customFunction
*/
function jsonify() {

  // Get the active spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get the active sheet
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // Get the selected range
  var selectedRange = sheet.getActiveRange();

  // Get values from the selected range
  var values = selectedRange.getValues();

  // Create an array to hold the JSON objects
  var jsonArray = [];

  // Get headers from the first row
  var headers = values[0];

  // Iterate through rows starting from the second row
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    var jsonObject = {};

    // Iterate through columns
    for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      jsonObject[headers[j]] = row[j];
    }

    // Add the JSON object to the array
    jsonArray.push(jsonObject);
  }

  // Convert the array to JSON string
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonArray, null, 2);

  // Log the JSON string (you can modify this part based on your use case)
  Logger.log(jsonString);

  // Optionally, you can return the JSON string
  return jsonString;
}
```

Comment: About `"Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (line 1)." This is strange because nowhere in my code am i calling SpreadsheetApp.getUi()`, does your actual Google Apps Script project have only your showing script? For example, I'm worried that your showing script is different from your actual script and the global variables might be used. If `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` is run as the global variable, such an error might occur. But, I'm not sure about your actual script. So, if my guess was not correct, I apologize.